# Need help installing xscreensaver will not start

Tags: pi-5

Hi I just installed Pi OS on my RPi 5 and i am trying to install and use xscreensaver but when I try to launch it from Preferences->xscreensaver settings it wont launch and in terminal `xscreensaver-settings` output this

```
xscreensaver-settings: 20:55:37: Gdk: gdk_x11_window_get_xid: assertion 'GDK_IS_X11_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

Comment: Bookworm uses Wayland NOT X so attempting to use any XWindows code is futile.

Comment: meaning ? I need to install another program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you don't need to install another program. But you do need to select `X` over `Wayland` (the new default).

From the terminal, type:

```bash
sudo raspi-config
```

`raspi-config` will start up with a [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) user interface.

Select `6  Advanced Options` - this will open a new screen/interface. In the new screen, select `A6  Wayland`. From the next screen, select `W1 X11  Open box ...` . Then select the `<OK>` "button" to get X11 instead of Wayland.